# Vue particles doesn't work with my project?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

**Hello everyone!** I currently integrated vue particle into my vue project! 
but for some reason something went wrong when I importing VueParticles inside Main.js file!This is snapshot from my terminal.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with `transform-runtime`, a dependency of vue-particles. You can fix it running:

`npm install babel-plugin-transform-runtime babel-preset-stage-2 --save-dev`

There's an issue at vue-particles discussing about that. You can check it [here](https://github.com/creotip/vue-particles/issues/27).